# Color changes after joining two meshes

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

[image]

Hi!
I'm a beginner in this and I'm having some troubles while sculpting which is after joining two meshes the color changes. I've been looking for answers everywhere and I often find the solution: select object/go to mesh/normals/recalculate outside... But the thing is it seems it doesn't work anymore, or at least I did it badly.
Besides, I don't know where's the option "normals" to then click recalculate outside, I only could find the shortkey (ctrl+n for recalculate outside) but again, it didn't work.

The version I'm using is 2.91.0... If you know the answer, please explain to me with details and images if it's possible, I don't know all the tools yet.

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2):

The green color is a [Face Set](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/editing/face_sets.html) that Blender automatically creates when you join two objects. Check out *Face Set* in the main menu of the *Sculpt mode*.

Face Sets can limit the effect of certain brushes in *Sculpt mode*, see brush options for details. There is also a Face Set brush to paint the color. That way you can highlight edge loops or important faces.

In the [Viewport Overlays](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html) you can turn it on/off and set the transparency of the color.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is your problem, but after joining them, go back to *Sculpting* and click on *Remesh* on the top of your screen with a low value of like [0.02]